# Swift Database with real time sync from the server

Tags: ios, swift, database, mongodb, realm

I'm actually creating my first personal project with swift which is an app that will present every prospect in the next NFL draft with info about them. I want to do kind of a database for the users to be able to browse around every player.
What I don't know how to do yet is how should I do to store the data. I thought about realm or coreData but I want to find a solution that will allow me to sync the data from a server to update the info in real-time for the users. There is no user data to update or save. I find the MongoDB Realm platform but I don't find a lot of resources about it. If anyone has any idea for how I should do, already thank you!

Have a nice day,
Matteo!

Comment: Realm fully supports cloud sync'ing as well as the new MongoDB Realm. It's mentioned here in the [Realm Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#default-realm) with the full docs [here](https://docs.realm.io/sync/). And the MongoDB Sync is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/). Unfortunately, asking for recommendations is off topic for stack overflow so the question may be closed. Check out the docs and write some code - let us know when you get stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made good experiences with Firestore. Its free (up to a certain usage) and has quite some good and clear documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answer.  Firebase is a fantastic realtime database to use for this specific idea.  It's extremely easy to get started and the documentation is straight forward.  I just started using it a couple weeks ago after switching over from AWS.